# Telnet/SSH to a Java `ServerSocket`

Tags: android, ssh, telnet

I created a really simple Java program that creates a `java.net.ServerSocket` on an open port, `x`, and waits for a connection using `accept ()`. I want to use `telnet`/`ssh` to connect to the program via port `x` so that I can communicate with said program. My problem is after I connect to the port, my program recognizes and accepts the connection, but `ssh` freezes. I'm assuming this is because I don't have the proper response. I just wanna know what I should be doing next. How do I respond?

I *could* use a library, but I'd like to understand what should come next. However, I would still really appreciate someone telling me if I really should be using a library. Also, I know some basic networking concepts like TCP/IP, OSI, and that data gets wrapped, sent, then unwrapped, but that's the extent of my networking knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` is probably much too complicated for what you want to achieve. It freezes because it waits for a response from your server that it probably never gets. `ssh` has also complicated security requirements that you probably don't want to implement for your simple server.

Why don't you start with something very basic on the client side as in this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html). From there on, you can still add features and functionality as needed.

Edit:

**Sending commands with telnet**:

Client Side:

Just issue `telnet host port`, there you type `say Hello World` and hit Enter.

Server side:

You receive a stream of bytes from your client. First you have to parse it as a String. Then you could simply split this String by looking for the first whitespace character. The string before that is your 'command', the part after the whitespace is your 'payload'.

In the example this would give you 'say' as the command and 'Hello World' as the payload.

Then compare the 'command' with a list of known commands, and based on what command you have you can then execute it with the payload as an argument.

Comment: Thanks, but I already read the tutorial. What I need now is to be able to send a command to my program. What I want to know for now is how I respond?

Comment: got it. thanks! btw, I tried writing to telnet's input stream, (the output stream of the socket my program has), but it never printed anything. Is there a special string I'm supposed to be replying with, i.e. `echo {message}`? Also, if my program weren't in localhost, how would I know what IP to telnet to?

Comment: I plan to use this on an android, for clarity's sake.

Comment: telnet will happily print whatever you send from your server, so you should already see something. If not, try to `flush` your OutputStream on the server. I would recommend not to go via IP but use the host name instead.

Comment: as in `google.com` host name? cause i'm telneting to the android device.

Comment: Hmm, that makes things interesting. I suppose your device IP is assigned using DHCP. I'm not sure whether they assign a permanent host name, too, that's what you would need in this case. Try a `nslookup` on your device IP and see what it tells you.

Comment: Hi, so I just learned my test droid is rooted, but my target droid is unrooted. If you aren't busy, I'd really appreciate it if you would answer the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7265751/152993

Answer (score 2):

SSH is a very specific protocol, involving encryption. Do you not just want to telnet to the socket, which uses plain-text by default?

Comment: I'm considering it. How would I go about sending the command "say Hello world" to my program via telnet?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are an genius at cryptography and networks, I doubt you can implement an SSH server. I don't know what your exact requirements are but you may take a look at this: http://www.sshtools.com/en/maverick-sshd/ It's a sshd in JAVA(but I haven't used it personally, so can't tell you much)

Comment: Hello again, Ravi. I'm no genius at cryptography, and don't know much about networks, so I'm probably going to end up using a library. Still, I wanna know how I can send messages to my simple server, mostly out of curiosity.