# Does an Android Device have to be rooted in order to telnet to it?

Tags: android, telnet

I created a `ServerSocket` that listens to port `9000` in my app, and I want to telnet to that port. It works on my rooted test device, but I need it to work on non-rooted devices, which it doesn't seem to do. I need to know if this only works on rooted devices, or if it should work on unrooted droids as well, implying that I just made a mistake in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work on any device, rooted or otherwise. As long as you aren't actually trying to access a privileged port (< 1024 if I recall correctly) or trying to use a port that's already in use.

Comment: alright, thanks for the confirmation. I'll recheck my code, and try and find where I screwed up. Just as a side-question, I'm running a `android.app.Service` to grab the data from the `java.net.Socket`s output stream, and I know I should be keeping that on a thread that is separate from the UI thread. Should I create a `Runnable` to handle that, should I make the `Service` implement `Runnable`, or should I just call the `Service` on a separate thread?

Comment: Typically I just make the Service implement Runnable and make the `Socket` a private variable of the `Service`.

Comment: how would you start the service up on a different thread? Do you have `onStartCommand ()` start the `run ()`, or do you have 'run ()' create the `Intent`?

Comment: oh ok, so inside `onStartCommand ()`, you have something like: `new Thread(this).run ()`?

Comment: That's right. You may want to save the thread to a variable so you can verify that you don't restart it (since `onStartCommand` can be called multiple times).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3047/discussion-between-anonymous-and-femi)